# Adding a Sphere on Mouse Click inside a Rectangle Grid

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add a Sphere whenever I click inside a Rectangle. Basically, I've made this 9X6 Grid using Rectangles.Attached is my code, I don't know what to add inside ActionEventHandler.

```
public void Settings(ActionEvent event) throws Exception
{   
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Settings.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
@FXML
ObservableList<Integer> comboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(3,4,5,6,7,8);
ObservableList<String> gridList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("9 X 6","15 X 10");
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    combo.setItems(comboList);
    gridb.setItems(gridList);
}


public void Grid() throws Exception {
    Stage primaryStage=new Stage();
    //AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Rectangle r = null;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++) {

    r = new Rectangle(70*j,70*i,70,70);
    r.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    root.getChildren().add(r);
    }
    }
    scene.setRoot(root);
    primaryStage.show();




    scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent me) -> {
        if(me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(me.getX(), me.getY(), 10, Color.BLUE);
            addEventHandler(root, circle);
            root.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
    });}
    private void addEventHandler(Group parent, Node node) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent me) -> {
                if(me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    parent.getChildren().remove(node);
                }
            });
}
```

If I use `scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent me)` this code, then I can add Circles (or Spheres) Anywhere randomly wherever I click even on the Grid Lines. I just want to have a single Sphere for a particular Rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Either you add event handlers to the individual `Rectangle`s or you use the `pickResult` property of the `MouseEvent` to check, if a `Rectangle` was clicked:

```
public static Rectangle getIntersectedRect(MouseEvent event) {
    Node n = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
    return (n instanceof Rectangle) ? (Rectangle) n : null;
}
```

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent me) -> {
    if(me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
        Rectangle rect = getIntersectedRect(me);
        if (rect != null) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(rect.getX()+35, rect.getY()+35, 10, Color.BLUE);
            addEventHandler(root, circle);
            root.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: Thanks , this helped me a lot. But there's a glitch, in the very last rectangle (i.e. Last row and last column ) on clicking it adds multiple circles instead of just adding one.